# Наложение элемента поверх изображения

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как наложить такой же крестик `<i>` поверх изображение в правый верхний угол?

```
//Изображение
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/YdOIzy1.jpg">

// Крестик
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">

<i class="zmdi zmdi-close"></i>
```

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть вот [здесь](https://htmlacademy.ru/courses/45)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="wrapper__img">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/YdOIzy1.jpg" alt="">
  <i class="zmdi zmdi-close"></i>
</div>

.wrapper__img {
position: relative;
}

.zmdi {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы сделать такое, нужно использовать `position: absolute;` для вашей иконки.
Ещё, иконке и картинки нужен родительский элемент, и чтобы всё не "полезло" нужно родителю установить `position: relative;`

```css
.image {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

/* Вам нужно вот это */
.image i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="image">
  <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/16.jpg">
  <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
</div>
```